# Change Exchange Server for a Single E-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I have hosted Exchange right now, with one mailbox containing around 3GB. I'm looking at switching over to Office 365.

Can I just change where my Exchange server lives, and all of my stuff will start syncing to the new server?

Or do I need to export my stuff, delete the current Exchange server out of Outlook, add the new one, and then import?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an online service to migrate all of my files from one server to another.